# Sending POST data through datatables ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I'm trying to make a simple ajax call in datatables that is reliant on a post array of IDs from a previous page's form. I am getting the error :

`Invalid JSON Response`

which tells me that my returned json array is probably empty or something and I have a feeling it has to do with the POST data not being sent to my php/sql external script on which ajax is requesting the data from.

I'm not sure how to test it as I don't know how to include the `$_POST` data in the URL to my external php page to outright trigger the script.

Heres my current datatables init and php from the results page:

```
<?php
include_once('../functions.php');
sec_session_start();
print_r($_POST['post_id']); <-- making sure the post data made it this far
?>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var compTable = $('#compTab').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "baddebt_ext_sql.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": 'json',
            "data": {"post_id": $_POST['post_id']}
        },                              
        "Columns": [
            { "data": "provider_num" },
            { "data": "provider_name"},
            { "data": "261_total_bed_debts", "sClass": "rightAlign" },
            { "data": "271_medicare_bad_debts", "sClass": "rightAlign" },
            { "data": "281_non_medicare_bad_debts", "sClass": "rightAlign" },
            { "data": "1_cost_to_charge_ratio", "sClass": "rightAlign" },
            { "data": "291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts", "sClass": "rightAlign" }
        ],
        "scrollY":        "600px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false,
        "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
        "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Filter All Fields By:" },
        "Dom": '<"clear">lfrtipT',
        "TableTools": {
              "sSwfPath" : "../php/tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" }
    });
```

and here is my SQL:

```
<?php
include_once('../link_costreport_2013.php');
if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
    $in = $_POST['post_id']; <-- THIS IS WHERE THE POST DATA IS SUPPOSED TO BE RECEIVED
}
$data = array();
foreach ($in as $id){
    $query = $link->prepare("SELECT id,provider_num, provider_name, 261_total_bed_debts, 271_medicare_bad_debts, 281_non_medicare_bad_debts, 1_cost_to_charge_ratio, 291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts
                FROM `s10`
                            WHERE `id` = :id");
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $results['261_total_bed_debts'] = "\$".number_format($results['261_total_bed_debts']);
    $results['271_medicare_bad_debts'] = "\$".number_format($results['271_medicare_bad_debts']);
    $results['281_non_medicare_bad_debts'] = "\$".number_format($results['281_non_medicare_bad_debts']);
    $results['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts'] = "\$".number_format($results['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts']);
    $results['provider_name'] = "<a id='".$results['id']."' data-toggle='modal' href='#provmodal' class='push'>".$results['provider_name']."</a>";
    $data[] = $results;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

If anyone knows how I can get my json array from this script without utilizing the previous pages $_POST data it is supposed to send, then I will gladly post it as well.

Basically I'm just wondering if there are any steps I am missing when it comes to feeding this array of IDs through my datatables ajax query and into the second page's sql. ( an example of the post_id array is like this: 
`Array ( [0] => 299 [1] => 1555 [2] => 3539 )`)

Comment: Did you try to put "dataType": 'json' with the ajax request?

Comment: @Nathan van der Werf  I just added it and am still receiving `invalid json response` wen't to check chrome dev tools and can't seem to find the ajax response in the network tab

Comment: @Nathan van der Werf scratch that found the response but I can't make any sense of it. It looks like the SQL page is returning undefined variables assumingly my post data 

:Edit - Undefined variable $in, which confims what I thought

Comment: What is the exact error ?

Comment: @Nathan van der Werf the two I am seeing are

`Undefined variable $in` and then after that it makes the foreach loop invalid so I receive an error for that as well.

Comment: It's because "post_id" is never sent to the php script through the ajax request. Add: "data": {"post_id": $_POST['post_id']} to the ajax request and you could check in the php script if $in is set

Comment: @NathanvanderWerf

Now I am getting

`uncaught reference error: $_POST is not defined` when it clearly is and is even printing the array at the top of the page. I also can no longer see a response from my baddebt_ext_sql.php page that ajax is requesting from. (In chrome dev tab that is)

Comment: can you update the code ?

Comment: Take a moment and look at your code carefully, compare it to the example on the datatables.net site.  You're mixing API calls between 1.10 and 1.9 versions.  For example, anything with Hungarian Notation -- like aoColumns, oLanguage, etc won't work with 1.10.  I'd start there!

Comment: @NathanvanderWerf it's up to date with what I have now.

Comment: @bpeterson76 I had no idea that I was using notation from different languages 0.0. I will go back and check

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing this problem is pretty easy.  Simply right mouse click and "inspect element" then choose the Network tab.  Toggle the transaction as you would in your interface.  You'll see a new network transaction in the network tab.

Click on that new network transaction -- it should have the address that you're defining in the ajax call.  The headers will show the variables you sent via post, response will show what the server returned.

The error is indicating that your response will fail if you paste the payload into jslint.com and evaluate it.  What the cause of that failure is will require more details than you've provided.

In the ajax example you use, "data" is the data that's being sent to the server.  To send a large amount of data in that post, I'd enclose your inputs in a form tag, then do a $.serialize or $.serializeArray on that form.  You can then send that serialized data over as a variable via the data attribute, where it will be posted to your server.  From there, just deal with the resulting post variables via PHP.

Please do update your code to use 1.10 API variables.  Support for the old ones will be deprecated in the future versions.

Comment: The form that posts this data is on another page and consists of checkboxes next to dynamic rows which are related to the ID (stored in mysql) of that row. The size of the next page's $_POST array can be anywhere between 1-6000 ids so I don't necessarily understand how your method would help at all.  I can't set them individually as any user may select any number of values. Also, what do you mean by toggle the transaction? Do you mean submit the form? And I can certainly post more code, but I have posted all that is relevant to this function that is in question

Comment: Updated based on your info.  $.serialize will be your friend on this one.  When I say toggle, I was assuming the case where you might be updating data.  Obviously, Datatables will send the initial post as you have configured it.  Many times I use a similar method to setup a number of filters for the data on an "advanced query" type UI, which is where the delayed transaction would be important.

Comment: Ok so do I want to serialize my $_POST['post_id'] and send it through ajax that way? How does one do that and then interpret it with php on the other side? Excuse my ignorance...datatables server side is really screwing me up this week.

Comment: doesn't GET return a string array? Could i just change my form to use get instead?

Comment: There's a big difference between submitting a form and the post/get variable you're defining on Datatables.  Datatables only submits what you tell it to.   If you have a form on the page, datatables isn't automatically submitting it's contents -- that's where the "data" option of the ajax event comes into play.  When you package your form as described, it'll be transmitted via get or post to your php page, where it will be available as either $_GET or $_POST -- or $_REQUEST if you want to handle either in php.